# Using Null coalescing operator in foreach with select expression

Tags: c#, linq, null, null-coalescing-operator

```
foreach (var item in Model.PublishedSong.RelatedSongs.Select((value, i) => new { value, i }) ?? Enumerable.Empty <dynamic>())
{

}
```

Related Songs may or may not be null, is there any way to use null coalescing operator here? I still get the error message:

> value cannot be null

Comment: Why don't test RelatedSongs for null *before* iterating them? What's the point in such complex code with ?? operator?

Comment: What are you expecting to be `null`, some part of `Model.PublishedSong.RelatedSong`, or some of the items within that collection?  Basically `Select` does not return `null` so the compiler is telling you that as it stands your null coalescing operator will never be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `RelatedSongs` is null, calling `Select` on it will throw a NullReferenceException, because the null coalescing operator is evaluated only *after* the left-hand side is resolved. And since resolving the left hand side results in an exception, it won't do you any good.

If you're using C# 6.0, you can use the Null Propagation operator - `?.` - to call Select only if `RelatedSongs` isn't null, and use the Null Coalescing operator otherwise:

```
// This will return null if Relatedsongs is null, or call Select otherwise.
foreach (var item in Model.PublishedSong.RelatedSongs?.Select((value, i) => new { value, i })  
                             ?? Enumerable.Empty <dynamic>())
{
}
```

If you're using C# 5 or earlier, you'll have to check for null manually:

```
foreach (var item in Model.PublishedSong.RelatedSongs != null 
                             ? Model.PublishedSong.RelatedSongs.Select((value, i) => new { value, i }) 
                             : Enumerable.Empty <dynamic>())
{
}
```

Comment: Personally I think it would be more readable  to check if the collection is `null` first and skip the `foreach` if it is.

Comment: @juharr I agree, but preferred to keep stylistic choices out of it and focus on the problem itself.

Comment: If you chose this kind of solution, please use `positive logic`, ie: eliminate one NOT operator, to arrive at something like:  `.. in RSongs == null ? Enum.empty() : Select() `

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[Edit: Removed simplification]

```
Model.PublishedSong
   .SelectMany(x=>
      (x.RelatedSongs??Enumerable.Empty<Song>())
         .Select((x,i) => new {Value = x, Index = i));
```

It evaluates to a single Enumerable rather than two.

Comment: This differs from OP. You're using ?? to alternate Select value, while OP uses it to choose between two sequences.

Comment: He's using it wrong there, left of ??, in his example, will never be null.

Answer (score 0):

I think @juharr's comment is good - it may be more readable if you perform the null check before the loop.  However, if you really want to use the null coalescing  operator this will do the trick:

```
foreach (var item in (Model.PublishedSong.RelatedSongs ?? Enumerable.Empty<TypeOfRelatedSong>()).Select((value, i) => new { value, i }))
{

}
```

You have to perform the null check before attempting to iterate over `RelatedSongs`.  In the example in your question you are doing it after attempting to iterate, hence the exception.